# Can't understand "unless" keyword in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm not a native English speaker. I know it sounds stupid nonetheless. I write in Python & C. But I can't quite understand how `unless` works.

Is it healthy to think of it from a logical standpoint? Eg, consider the `if` keyword: `if condition`. If `condition` is true, the code runs. What's the logical explanation for `unless`?

Is there any other way to think of it?

Comment: `unless` terminates program when the condition is `true`. It is the exact opposite of `if` that terminates program when the condition is `false`. 
It is safe to say `unless a` is the same thing as `if !a`

Comment: ya had me after the first sentence @Surge ; the way I read this now is...read the code within the logic flow branch and then say "`unless condition is true`". YMMV

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ruby unless modifier:

Syntax: code unless conditional

**Executes code if conditional is false.**

Example:

```
$var =  1
print "1 -- Value is set\n" if $var
print "2 -- Value is set\n" unless $var

$var = false
print "3 -- Value is set\n" unless $var
```

This will produce following result:

1 -- Value is set

3 -- Value is set

Answer (score 23):

`unless x` is equivalent to `if !x`

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way is: `unless` is an opposite of `if`. It works in the same places (I think) as `if`:

```
foo = nil
puts "This will not show" if foo
puts "But this will" unless foo

if foo then
  puts "This will not show"
end
unless foo
  puts "But this will"
end
```

It looks nicer in the code if you write `unless foo` instead of `if !foo` - but that is only my opinion. In the longer form, you can even use `else`, but *please, do not*.

Here is a [set of rules to follow to make the code more readable](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2008/12/01/unless-the-abused-ruby-conditional/).

Answer (score 1):

The way i think of it is to say:

"The block of code is going to be executed, **unless** the condition is true"

```
unless <condition>
  <code>
end
```

Comment: This is exactly how to read this. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

hungry = true

unless hungry

puts "I'm writing Ruby programs!"

else

puts "Time to eat!"

end

This is the easy way to understand